# difficulties in running a website written in both ruby and .net on windows

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, windows

I would like some advice on the difficulties one would have in order to run a website which is partially written in Ruby On Rails and partially written in a .NET language (C#, in my case). It may sound crazy to want to do this, but the current scenario in the company I work for may require me to create such a setup.
The situation is that we may acquire a system that is written in RoR, while our in-house system is entirely written in C#. The system to be acquired is reasonably complex and would not only save me and the other developer many hours of work, but would also serve the company (a school) before march, when classes begin. Please understand that not acquiring this system would probably mean a whole year without it, as many of the internal procedures of this school would have to rely on this system from the beginning (and this is the greatest reason why we are considering acquiring it now).
So now I am responsible for raising all the difficulties I may have in order to integrate these systems. My initial idea is to run the .NET system on IIS (as it is right now) and the RoR system on apache or nginx, listening on another port, of course. The UI's to both systems would be identical and would have to integrate seamlessly from the user point of view (links would point to the same domain on another port, but that would be fine). It probably is important to mention that we are using SQL Server as our DB. It may be helpful that I have decent Linux knowledge and experience (it is my personal system of choice).
So far, the technical difficulties I have thought of are:

1. A common cookie/session/auth cookie pool (such as a memcached server) so that we don't force users to login twice when accessing the different systems.
2. Switch the DB to postgresql or mysql (please, Ruby community, enlighten me) in case Ruby doesn't play well with SQL Server. I have heard "rumors" that this new system uses ActiveRecord to access the DB. Switching to postgresql is, either way, in the list of future changes, as it is my preferred DB.
3. Taking this system online. This would obviously require a VPS instead of a simple hosting service (which is what we currently have) and would greatly increase the burden on the IT department (me and one more person).
4. Possible problems of running RoR on Windows. This could mean a change to Linux + Mono for .NET and postgresql (mono running our systems wouldn't be a problem, I'm sure). This is however, a huge change, and it may scare my boss (and myself) a bit at first.

There are many other much more "administrative" problems, such as future maintenance and extensions would mean that I would either have to learn RoR and a bunch of other technologies (which, I must say, I would enjoy, but still..) or that we would have to pay more to have it maintained by this module original developers.

What I ask of you is what other problems do you see coming? I will have a technical meeting with the developers of this system monday and I would like to get there prepared to discuss these problems. I need to inform my boss of the problems ahead as well, of course.